# How to update already existing file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my project, I've got 2 elements that requires images (club got its own image and events)

In this question I focus only on club, since events solution will be the same probably.

I found a way to save the **file path inside of database** and in the same time **save file in my project folder**. Whenever I'm calling out image inside of view i do something like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $clubView->photo_patch) }}">
```

Everything works fine but when i try to update them (change file path inside db to new one and add new image to my public/storage/images)

**Everything falls with error:**

```
Call to a member function store() on string
```

**My question** is, how do I make it properly then?

Here is code I made to get this work:

**Controller class with route beneath it**

```
--------Create new object/club-------------------

public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $club = new Club;
        $club->name = $request->name;
        $club->description = $request->description;
        $club->address = $request->address;
        $club->city_id = $request->city_id;
        $club->user_id = $id;
        $club->photo_patch = $request->photo_patch->store('images','public');
        // $path = $request->photo_patch->store('images','public');

        // dd($club->photo_patch);
        $club->save();
        return redirect('clubs');
    }

Route::get('clubs/create', [App\Http\Controllers\ClubController::class, 'createView'])->name('clubs.createView');

--------Go to edit form-----------------------
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = Club::find($id);
        $city = City::get();
        // $city_id = City::find;
        return view('backend/club/edit', ['data' => $data],['city' =>$city]);
    }

Route::get('clubs/edit/'.'{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ClubController::class, 'edit'])->name('clubs.edit');

-----And then from edit, by pressing form button i do update function--------

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Club::find($request->id);
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->description = $request->description;
        $data->address = $request->address;
        $data->photo_patch = $request->photo_patch->store('images','public');
        $data->city_id = $request->city_id;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('clubs');
    }

Route::post('club/update', [App\Http\Controllers\ClubController::class, 'update'])->name('club.update');
```

Just to be clear, inside db i store path to my actual image which is inside of my app/public/storage/images.

Edit:

**Create form**

```
<form action="{{ route('club.create') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="container-sm">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="Club name">Club name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="enter name">

            <label for="Description">Description</label>
            <input type="textarea" rows="2" style="width:100%;height:60px;" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="enter description">

            <label for="Address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="enter address">

            <label for="inputState">City</label>
            <select id="inputState" name="city_id" class="form-control">
                @foreach($cities as $city)
                <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="photo_patch" accept="image/png, image/jpg">
            @error('photo_parch')
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{$message}}</div>
            @enderror

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Edit form**

```
<form action="{{ route('club.update') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="container-sm">
        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$data->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="city_id" value="{{$data->city_id}}">

            <label for="City exit form input form">City name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{$data->name}}">

            <label for="Description">Description</label>
            <input type="textarea" rows="2" style="width:100%;height:60px;" name="description" class="form-control" value="{{$data->description}}">

            <label for="Address exit form input form">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="{{$data->address}}">

            <label for="inputState">City</label>
            <select id="inputState" name="city_id" class="form-control">
                @foreach($city as $city)
                <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="photo_patch" accept="image/png, image/jpg">
            @error('photo_parch')
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{$message}}</div>
            @enderror

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Update</button>
        <div class="row">
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $data->photo_patch) }}" options="transform: 0.5">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to access a form field like a file. Try using `$club->photo_patch = $request->file('photo_patch')->store('images','public');` instead.

For this to work, your edit form should have a file input in it (as I suspect your create form does). In order to help you better, it would be useful to see your form html as well (for both forms).

Comment: It gives me null in return.

Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: Are you sure you're uploading the file with the request? It seems like the file is missing. Try debugging by using `dd($request->files())`.

Comment: My db stores path to image which is beeing saved in storage/images( in the same line its this line in create function $club->photo_patch = $request->store('images','public');). Then i can call it out in view by using @if($clubView->photo_patch)
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $clubView->photo_patch) }}">
            @else

Comment: Ah, so you don't mean to actually update the `photo_patch` field, right? Just remove that line from the `update` function then.
If you are trying to update it, however, you'll need a `<input type="file" />` element on your form, not just an `<img />` element.

Comment: I dont know what am I doing actually Sir, I updated my question so it should be a bit clearer.

Comment: Can you provide us with the html for your forms as well?

Comment: Your solution was succesfull. I just did mistake when implementing it. However if you want I can edit question and add html code.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for future readers to know what your forms look like :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can upload your image this way**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $imageName=date('d').time().date('m').'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('image'),$imageName);

    $id = Auth::id();
    $club = new Club;
    $club->name = $request->name;
    $club->description = $request->description;
    $club->address = $request->address;
    $club->city_id = $request->city_id;
    $club->user_id = $id;
    $club->photo_patch = $imageName;
    // $path = $request->photo_patch->store('images','public');

    // dd($club->photo_patch);
    $club->save();
    return redirect('clubs');
}
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $imageName=date('d').time().date('m').'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('image'),$imageName);

    $data = Club::find($request->id);
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->address = $request->address;
    $data->photo_patch = $imageName;
    $data->city_id = $request->city_id;
    $data->save();

    return redirect('clubs');
}
```

Comment: Is it somehow safer way Sir?

Comment: I changed my class for your method (also updated form name from photo_patch to image but I'm back at the same error as in the beginning :D

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function update(Club $club, Request $request) {

$club->update([
"name" => request->name,
...
]);
        return redirect('clubs');
    }


Route:
Route::get('update-club/{$club}' [AppControlller::class, 'update']);
```

Comment: Should this change anything? Or should i store my update requests inside of ->update ?

Comment: inside update and change your route too. 
also the link goes to update : <a href="{{ route('update' , $club->id ) }}">Update</a> and change route :  Route::get('update-club/{$club}' [AppControlller::class, 'update'])->name("update");